# mySQL many-to-many bi-directional relationships and queries

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database that has various object types, each defined by two-three letter codes, an abrievated list include:

- FIL - Files (fil_files table)
- TRA - Transactions (tra_transactions table)
- COM - Comments (com_comments table)
- PO Purchase Orders (po_purchase_orders table)

I have a table for relationships called obj_rels with the fields:

- id
- pri_type
- pri_type_id
- sec_type
- sec_type_id
- effective_on
- trashed_on
- trashed_by

The relationship table currently has about 95,000 records.

The object types could be either pri_type or sec_type.  For example, a Transaction and File could be related so TRA might be primary and FIL would be secondary.  Or a File and a Comment could be related so File FIL might be primary in that case, and COM secondary.

So I need a query to pull, for example, everything related to a file.

What I'm doing is:

```
SELECT pri_type, pri_type_id, sec_type, sec_type_id, effective_on
FROM obj_rels 
WHERE ( trashed_on = 0 OR ISNULL(trashed_on) ) AND pri_type = 'FIL' AND pri_type_id = 1234
UNION
SELECT sec_type, sec_type_id, pri_type, pri_type_id, effective_on
FROM obj_rels
WHERE ( trashed_on = 0 OR ISNULL(trashed_on) ) AND sec_type = 'FIL' AND sec_type_id = 1234
```

For a one off selection like this, it isn't too bad.  But when I do a larger query, say I need all of the transactions, and the number of files that are related to each individual transaction, the queries is significantly slowing down the operation of my web app.  The query I'm currently working on runs in about 0.4 seconds without the file & comments counts, and about 2.1 seconds with the counts.  Here is a pared down version of the query I'm trying to write:

```
SELECT *
FROM tra_transactions AS tra
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT pri_type, pri_type_id, COUNT(sec_type_id) AS cts
    FROM (
        SELECT pri_type, pri_type_id, sec_type, sec_type_id, effective_on
        FROM obj_rels WHERE pri_type = 'TRA' AND sec_type = 'FIL' AND ( trashed_on = 0 OR ISNULL(trashed_on) ) AND effective_on <= NOW()
        UNION
        SELECT sec_type, sec_type_id, pri_type, pri_type_id, effective_on
        FROM obj_rels WHERE sec_type = 'TRA' AND pri_type = 'FIL' AND ( trashed_on = 0 OR ISNULL(trashed_on) ) AND effective_on <= NOW()
    ) as qry 
    GROUP BY pri_type, pri_type_id
) AS rel ON rel.pri_type_id = tra.id
WHERE tra.ent_id = 40
```

Is there a better way to structure the relationship table to get ride of the union and sub queries I'm needing to run?

I'm wondering if would be better to store two entries per relationship so that the types that there is a record for each having the type as primary and secondary rather than running multiple queries together? That would double the size of the table, is that more efficient then running the join queries?  Is there a better architecture?

Thanks in advance!

... comment ... I was asked to provide the indexes.  Here is the Create statement for the obj_rels table ... I'm not very good at indexes, so I've probably done a bit of overkill:

```
CREATE TABLE `obj_rels` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pri_type` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pri_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sec_type` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sec_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `effective_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `trashed_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trashed_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `types` (`pri_type`,`sec_type`),
  KEY `pri_type` (`pri_type`),
  KEY `pri_type_id` (`pri_type_id`),
  KEY `sec_type` (`sec_type`),
  KEY `sec_type_id` (`sec_type_id`),
  KEY `trashed_on` (`trashed_on`),
  KEY `pri_type_id_2` (`pri_type_id`,`pri_type`,`trashed_on`),
  KEY `sec_type_id_2` (`sec_type_id`,`sec_type`,`trashed_on`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=94530 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: what do your `indexes` look like for this table?

Comment: `UNION` implicitly fetches distinct records, which makes this operation more expensive. Using `UNION ALL` might speed this query up seriously.

Comment: your first query could just be one as well, just use `OR` instead of creating a whole new query with `UNION`

Comment: Not 100% sure about MySQL, but I think it doesn't index `null` values, except when the indexed fields also contain a non null value. This means that `trashed_on = 0 OR ISNULL(trashed_on)` is an expensive operation if there is an index on `trashed_on` alone, and no index that combined `trashed_on` with another column. The `or` makes it more expensive in itself, and if you could make `trashed_on` mandatory, default 0, that would improve things too.

Comment: I've set the default trashed_on value to 0 and added a NOT NULL tag to the field on all of the tables, and searched just if trashed_on=0.  I also tried using a UNION ALL instead of UNION, and it sped the bigger query I started with from 2.1 down to 0.85 seconds.  Still would appreciate any other suggestions on ways to improve the infrastructure. Thanks!